# Vectorizing "balance sheet"-like data

Tags: python, pandas, refactoring, vectorization

The problem is the following: how to vectorize situations where a value on the next line of a dataframe depends on a previous one? I want to avoid the for loop.

The row logic I need for the desired column is, given an "open balance" different from 0 or NaN in row[0]:

(1) row_t.open_balance = row_t-1.close_balance

(2) row_t.close_balance = row_t.open_balance + row_t.additions - row_t.subtractions

Besides being slow, the infamous for loop leads me to all kinds of `SettingWithCopyWarning` situations.

Can anyone help here? I've tried "helper columns" to no avail because of equation #2 above.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First off, please use ``` to indicate what is code at the beginning and end of your code if multi-line, and ` if single line. This helps with readability. Second, we need a reproducible example. How are we supposed to help you if we have no example of your code that we can play with on our end?

Answer (score 0):

First, had to create reproducible example so I can try to answer this question. Remember to do this next time you ask a question.

Here I simulate additions and subtractions.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

additions = np.random.randint(0, 100, 10)
subtractions = np.random.randint(0, 50, 10)
net_change = pd.DataFrame({'balance': list(additions - subtractions)})

net_change

    balance
0   44
1   13
2   70
3   -36
4   73
5   -6
6   54
7   30
8   39
9   80
```

Create DataFrame with starting balance of 0.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'balance': [0]})
df

balance
0   0
```

Concatenate the DataFrame with net_change.

```
df = pd.concat([df, net_change], ignore_index=True)
df

    balance
0   0
1   44
2   13
3   70
4   -36
5   73
6   -6
7   54
8   30
9   39
10  80
```

Then use [pandas.DataFrame.cumsum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) to get the cumulative close balance which is what I assume is what you're are to compute.

```
df.cumsum()

    balance
0   0
1   44
2   57
3   127
4   91
5   164
6   158
7   212
8   242
9   281
10  361
```